# NGINX location config are not all working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, react-router

I have a MERN stack application that is being hosted on a `AWS ec2 instance` using `pm2` to host the server, and `nginx` to host the frontend. Essentially, when I go to my ec2 public ip, it automatically loads the `/login` page perfectly. However, if I try fresh, I then get `Cannot GET /login`. In the console I am getting `GET http://my_ec2_public_ip/login 404 (Not Found)`. Does anyone know why???

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my_ec2_public_ip;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

`simplified version of server/index.js` (hosted with `pm2`):

```
// routes
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/dashboard", dashboardRoutes);

// just added
app.use("/", authRoutes);
app.use("/login", authRoutes);

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`));
```

simplified version of `client/App.js` (hosted with nginx):

```
function App() {
    const user = localStorage.getItem("token");

    return (
        <Routes>
            {user && <Route path="/dashboard/:_id" exact element={<Main />} />}

            <Route path="/login" exact element={<Login />} />
            <Route path="/" element={<Navigate replace to="/login" />} />
        </Routes>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**error from `sudo nano /var/log/nginx/error.log`:**

```
2023/03/12 13:12:49 [alert] 3456#3456: *2 open socket #10 left in connection 3
2023/03/12 13:12:49 [alert] 3456#3456: aborting
2023/03/12 13:19:57 [error] 3513#3513: *13 open() "/var/www/html/Core/Skin/Login.aspx" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 43.154.8.109, server: 3>
```

Comment: Your nginx logs would be helpful here. Have you setup CloudWatch Logs Agent on the EC2 to forward the nginx logs to CloudWatch? Or just directly check the logs via ssh if you have access. (Not the best practice though, but it doesn't look like a clean architecture anyways!)

Comment: I have updated with the error that I am getting from nginx. @roxch

Comment: It appears to me that the nginx reverse proxy is forwarding the direct requests to `/login` to the your node server where no route is defined for this path. You should check your routings in Node. Anything else seems OK here

Comment: @roxch I have updated `server/index.js` in the question with what I added. Now when I go to `/login`  it just continuously loads and then cant be reached